# Convert Numpy Arrrays to a Tensor

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning

I converted a file to dataframe with pandas and now I would like to train a Deep Learning model via TensorFlow. I don't succeed to train the model: after dividing in training and test set, when I go to compile the model it tells me

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type 
numpy.ndarray).
```

I thought the problem was that the numpy arrays had different sizes, but despite performing padding (in this way all the arrays had the same dimension inside the column), the problem was not solved.
Below I insert an example of a column I have inside the dataset: if I wanted to transform this into a tensor, how should I do it?

```
df = pd.read_parquet('example.parquet')
df['column']

0                            [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
1          [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
2          [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
3                      [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
4                   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
                         ...                        
115                          [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
116    [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...
117     [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
118    [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...
119                    [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Clearly I have inserted the original column, not the one on which I padded unsuccessfully.

These are the steps that I did to train the model, if they can be useful

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
Y = label_encoder.fit_transform(Y)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)
#create model
model = Sequential()

#add model layers
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(20, activation='softmax', input_shape=(X_train.shape)))

# compile model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=50)
```

UPDATE: Complete traceback

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported 
object type numpy.ndarray).
--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call 
last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16380/3421148994.py in <module>
  1 from livelossplot import PlotLossesKeras
  2 
----> 3 model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), 
epochs=50, callbacks=[PlotLossesKeras()])

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, 
epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, 
shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, 
validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, 
max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
1132          training_utils.RespectCompiledTrainableState(self):
1133       # Creates a `tf.data.Dataset` and handles batch and epoch 
iteration.
-> 1134       data_handler = data_adapter.get_data_handler(
1135           x=x,
1136           y=y,

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in get_data_handler(*args, 
**kwargs)
1381   if getattr(kwargs["model"], "_cluster_coordinator", None):
1382     return _ClusterCoordinatorDataHandler(*args, **kwargs)
-> 1383   return DataHandler(*args, **kwargs)
1384 
1385
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weight, batch_size, steps_per_epoch, initial_epoch, epochs, shuffle, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, model, steps_per_execution, distribute)
   1136 
   1137     adapter_cls = select_data_adapter(x, y)
-> 1138     self._adapter = adapter_cls(
   1139         x,
   1140         y,

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, sample_weight_modes, batch_size, epochs, steps, shuffle, **kwargs)
    228                **kwargs):
    229     super(TensorLikeDataAdapter, self).__init__(x, y, **kwargs)
--> 230     x, y, sample_weights = _process_tensorlike((x, y, sample_weights))
    231     sample_weight_modes = broadcast_sample_weight_modes(
    232         sample_weights, sample_weight_modes)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in _process_tensorlike(inputs)
   1029     return x
   1030 
-> 1031   inputs = tf.nest.map_structure(_convert_numpy_and_scipy, inputs)
   1032   return tf.__internal__.nest.list_to_tuple(inputs)
   1033
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py in map_structure(func, *structure, **kwargs)
    867 
    868   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 869       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    870       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    871 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    867 
    868   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 869       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    870       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    871 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in _convert_numpy_and_scipy(x)
   1024       if issubclass(x.dtype.type, np.floating):
   1025         dtype = backend.floatx()
-> 1026       return tf.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=dtype)
   1027     elif _is_scipy_sparse(x):
   1028       return _scipy_sparse_to_sparse_tensor(x)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    204     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    205     try:
--> 206       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    207     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    208       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in convert_to_tensor_v2_with_dispatch(value, dtype, dtype_hint, name)
   1428     ValueError: If the `value` is a tensor not of given `dtype` in graph mode.
   1429   """
-> 1430   return convert_to_tensor_v2(
   1431       value, dtype=dtype, dtype_hint=dtype_hint, name=name)
   1432 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in convert_to_tensor_v2(value, dtype, dtype_hint, name)
   1434 def convert_to_tensor_v2(value, dtype=None, dtype_hint=None, name=None):
   1435   """Converts the given `value` to a `Tensor`."""
-> 1436   return convert_to_tensor(
   1437       value=value,
   1438       dtype=dtype,

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\profiler\trace.py in wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    161         with Trace(trace_name, **trace_kwargs):
    162           return func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 163       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    164 
    165     return wrapped

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, dtype_hint, ctx, accepted_result_types)
   1564 
   1565     if ret is None:
-> 1566       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1567 
   1568     if ret is NotImplemented:
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_conversion_registry.py in _default_conversion_function(***failed resolving arguments***)
     50 def _default_conversion_function(value, dtype, name, as_ref):
     51   del as_ref  # Unused.
---> 52   return constant_op.constant(value, dtype, name=name)
     53 
     54 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name)
    269     ValueError: if called on a symbolic tensor.
    270   """
--> 271   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
    272                         allow_broadcast=True)
    273 
    ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    281       with trace.Trace("tf.constant"):
    282         return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
--> 283     return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    284 
    285   g = ops.get_default_graph()

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    306 def _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape):
    307   """Creates a constant on the current device."""
--> 308   t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    309   if shape is None:
    310     return t

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    104       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
    105   ctx.ensure_initialized()
--> 106   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
    107 
    108 

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

Comment: Please, update with the complete traceback.

Comment: I updated the first message with the complete traceback

Comment: would show shape of your x_train, seems data type doesn't match some objects are there, try `X.astype(np.float32)`

Comment: I had this error 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: The shape of my X is (120,3), the shape of my X_train is (84,3)

Comment: Examine `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test` - particularly `shape` and `dtype`.  The dtypes should be numeric (float) and the the X shapes 2d.

Comment: Dtype are all object. X_train.dtypes gives this

column1    object
column2          object
column3    object
dtype: object

Comment: My guess is that you need to reshape your array. It is probably a standard array within an array, whereas you need a 2 dim numpy array. Could you provide details on the `shape` of X?

Comment: X shape is (120,3) and every column has the structure I wrote in the first post. They are, therefore, arrays of arrays and not all elements have the same size. It's okay even if I can only get the solution for one of the columns in the dataframe. As I wrote, I tried making all the elements the same size by inserting padding, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are currently working on padded data. So now after padding the data you do `Scaling`. After doing this you X shape is (120,3) and (84,3) for train and test respectively.

Now the first obvious error is in the below line

```
model.add(Dense(20, activation='softmax', input_shape=(X_train.shape)))
```

You don't specify the dimension of `batch` in the `input_shape`. To put it in a simpler way say you are giving images to the model then what will you write in the `input_shape` in case of an 1 channel image? It will as below.

```
height = 224
width = 224
model.add(Dense(20, activation='softmax', input_shape=(height, width)))

# In your case you have written
model.add(Dense(20, activation='softmax', input_shape=(120, 3)))
```

This tells the model that corresponding to each input of shape (120,3) there is some label which is not the case and hence you are supposed to pass only the dimension of features like below

```
model.add(Dense(20, activation='softmax', input_shape=(3,)))
```

After this the error should be removed. Also, I don't see you using `batch_size` parameter in `model.fit` and you should use it.

Second thing that I see is not a syntactical error but a methodological error in the below code.

```
#create model
model = Sequential()
#add model layers
model.add(BatchNormalization()) # RED FLAG
model.add(Dense(20, activation='softmax', input_shape=(X_train.shape)))
```

You are not supposed to use `BatchNormalization` on inputs. The main reason to use `BatchNormalization` is to increase the training speed of the models and even then not on inputs. Also, the important thing to note is that `BatchNormalization` is `Normalization` on training batch and not on the whole dataset and hence is of little use if you are not using large batch size which could represent the whole population.

UPDATE:
You are not padding correctly. The output of X.shape after padding should be `( _ , _ )` and not `( _ , )`. So, do the following

```
# Creating some random data
random_array = []
for i in range(20):
    random_array.append([i for i in range(i+1)])

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['values'] = random_array

for i in range (0, len(df['values'])):
    pad_size = 21 - len(df['values'][i])
    df['values'][i] = np.pad(df['values'][i], (pad_size, 0))

final_array = np.array([np.array(i) for i in df['values']])
print(final_array.shape) # This will give (20, 21) and not (20,)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I provided more infos in the next answer. Unfortunately error is still there

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you so much for your response. Unfortunately I tried doing what you said but the problem still remained. I report below the script that I used with all the information related to the type and shape of the features.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
#Import Dataset
df = pd.read_parquet('toydataset.parquet')
#Selected only one column of the dataset
X = df['column1']
Y= df['label']
```

Now I provide infos for the selected column

```
X.shape
(120,)
X
0                            [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
1          [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
2          [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
3                      [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
4                   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
                             ...                        
115                          [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
116    [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...
117     [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
118    [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...
119                    [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
Name: column1, Length: 120, dtype: object
```

Now I'm going to pad the column. The maximum lenght of the array is 13040

```
#First encode the label
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
Y = label_encoder.fit_transform(Y)
#Padding the column
for i in range (0, len(df['column1'])):
    pad_size = 13040-len(df['column1'][i])
    df['column1'][i] = np.pad(df['column1'][i], (pad_size, 0))
    #print(df['column1'][i])
```

This is the result

```
X=df['column1']
X
0      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
1      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
2      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
3      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
4      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
                             ...                        
115    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
116    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
117    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
118    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
119    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
Name: column1, Length: 120, dtype: object
```

Now I'm going to split the dataset

```
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)
X_train.shape
(84,)
X_test.shape
(36,)
y_train.shape
(84,)
y_test.shape
(36,)
```

I also provide the result for X_train

```
X_train
30     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
53     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
118    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
9      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
33     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
                             ...                        
106    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
14     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
92     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
51     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
102    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
Name: column1, Length: 84, dtype: object
```

Then I followed the proposed step

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20, activation='softmax', input_shape=(84,)))
#I tried with input shape (84,) but also with other numbers but the result is always the same
# compile model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=50, batch_size=32)
```

This is the complete traceback

```
    ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\util\structure.py in normalize_element(element, element_signature)
    105         if spec is None:
--> 106           spec = type_spec_from_value(t, use_fallback=False)
    107       except TypeError:

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\util\structure.py in type_spec_from_value(element, use_fallback)
    485 
--> 486   raise TypeError("Could not build a TypeSpec for %r with type %s" %
    487                   (element, type(element).__name__))

TypeError: Could not build a TypeSpec for 30     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
53     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
118    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
9      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
33     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
                             ...                        
106    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
14     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
92     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
51     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
102    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
Name: column1, Length: 84, dtype: object with type Series
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16012/2272230314.py in <module>
     24 # compile model
     25 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
---> 26 model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=50, batch_size=1)
     27 
     28 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1132          training_utils.RespectCompiledTrainableState(self):
   1133       # Creates a `tf.data.Dataset` and handles batch and epoch iteration.
-> 1134       data_handler = data_adapter.get_data_handler(
   1135           x=x,
   1136           y=y,

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in get_data_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1381   if getattr(kwargs["model"], "_cluster_coordinator", None):
   1382     return _ClusterCoordinatorDataHandler(*args, **kwargs)
-> 1383   return DataHandler(*args, **kwargs)
   1384 
   1385 
   ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weight, batch_size, steps_per_epoch, initial_epoch, epochs, shuffle, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, model, steps_per_execution, distribute)
   1136 
   1137     adapter_cls = select_data_adapter(x, y)
-> 1138     self._adapter = adapter_cls(
   1139         x,
   1140         y,

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, sample_weight_modes, batch_size, epochs, steps, shuffle, **kwargs)
    320     indices_dataset = indices_dataset.flat_map(slice_batch_indices)
    321 
--> 322     dataset = self.slice_inputs(indices_dataset, inputs)
    323 
    324     if shuffle == "batch":

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in slice_inputs(self, indices_dataset, inputs)
    346     dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((
    347         indices_dataset,
--> 348         tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(inputs).repeat()
    349     ))
    350 
    ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py in from_tensors(tensors)
    604       Dataset: A `Dataset`.
    605     """
--> 606     return TensorDataset(tensors)
    607 
    608   @staticmethod

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py in __init__(self, element)
   3823   def __init__(self, element):
   3824     """See `Dataset.from_tensors()` for details."""
-> 3825     element = structure.normalize_element(element)
   3826     self._structure = structure.type_spec_from_value(element)
   3827     self._tensors = structure.to_tensor_list(self._structure, element)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\util\structure.py in normalize_element(element, element_signature)
    109         # the value. As a fallback try converting the value to a tensor.
    110         normalized_components.append(
--> 111             ops.convert_to_tensor(t, name="component_%d" % i))
    112       else:
    113         if isinstance(spec, sparse_tensor.SparseTensorSpec):

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\profiler\trace.py in wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    161         with Trace(trace_name, **trace_kwargs):
    162           return func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 163       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    164 
    165     return wrapped
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, dtype_hint, ctx, accepted_result_types)
   1564 
   1565     if ret is None:
-> 1566       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1567 
   1568     if ret is NotImplemented:

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in _constant_tensor_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
    344                                          as_ref=False):
    345   _ = as_ref
--> 346   return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    347 
    348 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name)
    269     ValueError: if called on a symbolic tensor.
    270   """
--> 271   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
    272                         allow_broadcast=True)
    273 
    ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    281       with trace.Trace("tf.constant"):
    282         return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
--> 283     return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    284 
    285   g = ops.get_default_graph()

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    306 def _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape):
    307   """Creates a constant on the current device."""
--> 308   t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    309   if shape is None:
    310     return t

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    104       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
    105   ctx.ensure_initialized()
--> 106   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
    107 
    108 

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

UPDATE: with padding I've solved the conversion problem. Now this is my code

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv1D, Flatten
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
df = pd.read_parquet('toydataset.parquet')
Y= df['label']
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
Y = label_encoder.fit_transform(Y)
#New Padding
for i in range (0, len(df['column1'])):
    pad_size = 13040 - len(df['column1'][i])
    df['column1'][i] = np.pad(df['column1'][i], (pad_size, 0))

final_array = np.array([np.array(i) for i in df['column1']])
X=final_array
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)
#create model
model = Sequential()

#add model layers
#model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(20, activation='softmax', input_shape=(13040,)))

# compile model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=50)
```

Now there is this problem

```
     ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 20) are incompatible
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_6140/3165204354.py in <module>
      8 # compile model
      9 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
---> 10 model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=50)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1182                 _r=1):
   1183               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1184               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1185               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1186                 context.async_wait()

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    883 
    884       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 885         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    886 
    887       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    931       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    932       initializers = []
--> 933       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    934     finally:
    935       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    757     self._graph_deleter = FunctionDeleter(self._lifted_initializer_graph)
    758     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
--> 759         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    760             *args, **kwds))
    761 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3064       args, kwargs = None, None
   3065     with self._lock:
-> 3066       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   3067     return graph_function
   3068 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3461 
   3462           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3463           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3464           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3465 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
3296     arg_names = base_arg_names + missing_arg_names
   3297     graph_function = ConcreteFunction(
-> 3298         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
   3299             self._name,
   3300             self._python_function,

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes, acd_record_initial_resource_uses)
   1005         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
   1006 
-> 1007       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
   1008 
   1009       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    666         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
    667         with OptionalXlaContext(compile_with_xla):
--> 668           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    669         return out
    670 ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    992           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    993             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 994               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    995             else:
    996               raise

ValueError: in user code:
     C:\Users\Luigi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:853 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\Users\Luigi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:842 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\Users\Luigi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1286 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Users\Luigi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2849 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Users\Luigi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3632 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\Luigi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:835 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    C:\Users\Luigi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:788 train_step
        loss = self.compiled_loss(
    C:\Users\Luigi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py:201 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    C:\Users\Luigi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py:141 __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    C:\Users\Luigi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py:245 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    C:\Users\Luigi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\Luigi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py:1665 categorical_crossentropy
        return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
    C:\Users\Luigi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\Luigi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py:4839 categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    C:\Users\Luigi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py:1161 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 20) are incompatible
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've solved the tensor conversion problem. When I go to create the model, what should I put as input_shape?
X_train.shape is (84, 13040), X_test.shape is (36, 13040), y_train.shape is (84, _ ) and y_test.shape is (36, _ ). I tried with input_shape = (84, _ ) or (84, 13040) but it gives me error at the first epoch

Comment: `model.add(Dense(20, activation='softmax', input_shape=(13040,)))` Also you won't get any good results as your input is very large but you don't have that large number of samples.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help you are giving me. Clearly this is an example to understand how training works, I know I need many more samples. I still have a problem in the first epoch, I updated my previous answer.